# Problema con validación de ReactiveForm en Angular

Tags: angular, formularios, reactiveformsmodule, angular-reactive-forms

Tengo un problema con este formulario reactivo en Angular, no se está validando correctamente, creé el método isFormValid para hacer debug y me dice que todos los campos son válidos pero aún así marca el formulario como inválido (`console.log(updateForm.invalid)` da como resultado true), y como el botón de envío tiene la propiedad `[disabled]="isFormEmpty || updateForm.invalid"` pues no se está activando, antes de que pregunten ya descarté que sea la combinación de `formControlName` con `[(ngModel)]` porque lo tengo así en todos los otros componentes de mi aplicación y no me ha dado ningún problema.

También ya intenté cambiar el `updateOn: 'blur'` por `updateOn: 'change'` a sugerencia de chatgpt y tampoco funcionó, por último, para asegurarme de que no fuera por la propiedad isFormEmpty que verifica si el formulario está vacío (empieza en true y se actualiza a false con el método onFieldChange cuando se ha llenado al menos un campo), cambié la propiedad disabled así `[disabled]="isFormEmpty"` y no me dio ningún problema, se activó el botón correctamente cuando llené un campo.

Alguna idea de cual puede ser el error?

### El código de mi componente

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { GetGroupsService } from 'src/app/services/grupos/get-groups.service';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Moment } from 'moment';
import {
  FormsModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  AbstractControl,
  ValidationErrors,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-actualizar-alumno',
  templateUrl: './actualizar-alumno.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./actualizar-alumno.component.scss']
})

export class ActualizarAlumnoComponent implements OnInit {

  protected id: number
  protected nombre: string
  protected ap_p: string
  protected ap_m: string
  protected sexo: string
  protected birthdate: string
  protected apoyo: number
  protected grupo: number
  protected isFormEmpty: boolean
  protected listaGrupos: any[] | null
  protected namePattern: RegExp
  protected updateForm: FormGroup<ReactiveFormsModule>



  constructor(private grupos: GetGroupsService, private router: Router) {

    this.id = 0
    this.nombre = ""
    this.ap_p = ""
    this.ap_m = ""
    this.sexo = ""
    this.birthdate = ""
    this.apoyo = 0
    this.grupo = 0
    this.isFormEmpty = true
    this.listaGrupos = []
    this.namePattern = new RegExp('^(?=.*[aeiouüAEIOUÜáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑ])[a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚñÑüÜ\s ]+$')

    this.updateForm = new FormGroup<ReactiveFormsModule>({

      id: new FormControl(this.id, {
        validators: [Validators.required, Validators.min(1)],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }),

      nombre: new FormControl(this.nombre, {
        validators: [Validators.pattern(this.namePattern), Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(30)],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }),

      ap_p: new FormControl(this.ap_p, {
        validators: [Validators.pattern(this.namePattern), Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(30)],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }),

      ap_m: new FormControl(this.ap_m, {
        validators: [Validators.pattern(this.namePattern), Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(30)],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }),

      sexo: new FormControl(this.sexo, {
        validators: [this.sexValidator],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }),

      birthdate: new FormControl(this.birthdate, {
        validators: [this.dateAntiquityValidator, this.dateFormatValidator],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }),

      apoyo: new FormControl(this.apoyo, {
        validators: [Validators.min(1.0), Validators.max(10.0)],
        updateOn: 'blur'
      }),

      grupo: new FormControl(this.grupo, {
        validators: [Validators.min(1)],
        updateOn: 'change'
      })

    })
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.grupos.obtenerGrupos().subscribe((data: object[]) => {
      this.listaGrupos = data
    }, (error: Error) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error))
      this.listaGrupos = null
    })
  }


  protected volver(): void {
    const respuesta: boolean = confirm(`¿Está seguro de que desea abandonar la página?
  Se perderán todos los cambios no guardados`)

    respuesta ? this.router.navigate(['/alumnos']) : null
  }

  protected actualizar(): void {
    console.log(this.updateForm.value)
  }

  protected onFieldChange(): void {
    // Verifica si al menos uno de los campos del formulario tiene un valor
    this.isFormEmpty = Object.values(this.updateForm.value).every(value => !value)
    console.log(this.isFormEmpty)
  }

  protected isFieldValid(control: string) {

    const invalidField: boolean = this.updateForm.get(control)?.invalid! && this.updateForm.get(control)?.touched!
    if (invalidField) {
      console.log(`El campo ${control} no es válido`)
      
    } else {
      console.log(`El campo ${control} es válido`)

    }

    console.log(this.updateForm.invalid)
    console.log(this.updateForm.value)
  }
  //Esta wea sirve para validar que la fecha de nacimiento tenga al menos cuatro años de antiguedad
  private dateAntiquityValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {

    const fecha: Date = control.value
    const fechaActual: Moment = moment()
    const fechaFormulario: Moment = moment(fecha, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    const fechaMinima: Moment = fechaActual.clone().subtract(4, 'years')
    const isDateOldEnough: boolean = fechaFormulario.isSameOrBefore(fechaMinima)

    return isDateOldEnough ? null : { antiguedadFecha: true }
  }

  //Esto es pa comprobar que sea una fecha válida
  private dateFormatValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {

    const dateString: string = control.value
    const fecha: Date = new Date(dateString)
    //console.log(fecha)
    const validDate: boolean = fecha instanceof Date && !isNaN(fecha.valueOf())
    //console.log(validDate)
    return validDate ? null : { validezFecha: true }
  }

  private sexValidator(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {

    const sexo: string = control.value
    const validSex: boolean = sexo == "H" || sexo == "M"
    return validSex ? null : { sexoInvalido: true }
  }

}
```

### El de mi plantilla

```
<div>
    <h2>Actualizar alumno</h2>
    <form method="put" [formGroup]="updateForm" (submit)="actualizar()">
        <label id="id">
            Introduzca el id del alumno:
            <input type="number" name="id" id="ID" min="1" placeholder="ID" [(ngModel)]="id" formControlName="id"
                [ngClass]="{'campo-invalido': updateForm.get('id')?.invalid && updateForm.get('id')?.touched}"
                (ngModelChange)="isFieldValid('id')">
            <span class="error" *ngIf=" updateForm.get('id')?.hasError('required') && updateForm.get('id')?.touched">
                El id es obligatorio
            </span>
            <span class="error" *ngIf=" updateForm.get('id')?.hasError('min') && updateForm.get('id')?.touched">
                El id debe ser mayor a 0
            </span>
        </label>
        <label id="nombre">
            Introduzca el nombre:
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="name" placeholder="Nombre" [(ngModel)]="nombre"
                formControlName="nombre" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange(); isFieldValid('nombre')"
                [ngClass]="{'campo-invalido': updateForm.get('nombre')?.invalid && updateForm.get('nombre')?.touched}">
            <span class="error"
                *ngIf="updateForm.get('nombre')?.hasError('pattern') && updateForm.get('nombre')?.touched">
                Los nombres y apellidos no pueden contener <br>caracteres especiales salvo acentos, "ñ" y "ü"<br>
                Adicionalmente, deben incluir al menos una vocal
            </span>
            <span class="error"
                *ngIf="updateForm.get('nombre')?.hasError('minlength') && updateForm.get('nombre')?.touched">
                Los nombres y apellidos deben tener al menos <br> 3 caracteres de longitud
            </span>
            <span class="error"
                *ngIf="updateForm.get('nombre')?.hasError('maxlength') && updateForm.get('nombre')?.touched">
                Los nombres y apellidos no pueden tener más de <br> 30 caracteres de longitud
            </span>
        </label>
        <label id="ap_p">
            Introduzca el apellido paterno:
            <input type="text" name="apellido_p" id="ap_p" placeholder="Apellido paterno" [(ngModel)]="ap_p"
                formControlName="ap_p" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange();  isFieldValid('ap_p')"
                [ngClass]="{'campo-invalido': updateForm.get('ap_p')?.hasError('minlength') && updateForm.get('ap_p')?.touched}">
            <span class="error" *ngIf="updateForm.get('ap_p')?.hasError('pattern') && updateForm.get('ap_p')?.touched">
                Los nombres y apellidos no pueden contener <br>caracteres especiales salvo acentos, "ñ" y "ü"<br>
                Adicionalmente, deben incluir al menos una vocal
            </span>
            <span class="error"
                *ngIf="updateForm.get('ap_p')?.hasError('minlength') && updateForm.get('ap_p')?.touched">
                Los nombres y apellidos deben tener al menos <br> 3 caracteres de longitud
            </span>
            <span class="error"
                *ngIf="updateForm.get('ap_p')?.hasError('maxlength') && updateForm.get('ap_p')?.touched">
                Los nombres y apellidos no pueden tener más de <br> 30 caracteres de longitud
            </span>
        </label>
        <label id="ap_m">
            Introduzca el apellido materno:
            <input type="text" name="apellido_m" id="ap_m" placeholder="Apellido materno" [(ngModel)]="ap_m"
                formControlName="ap_m" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange(); isFieldValid('ap_m')"
                [ngClass]="{'campo-invalido': updateForm.get('ap_m')?.invalid && updateForm.get('ap_m')?.touched}">
            <span class="error" *ngIf="updateForm.get('ap_m')?.hasError('pattern') && updateForm.get('ap_m')?.touched">
                Los nombres y apellidos no pueden contener <br>caracteres especiales salvo acentos, "ñ" y "ü"<br>
                Adicionalmente, deben incluir al menos una vocal
            </span>
            <span class="error"
                *ngIf="updateForm.get('ap_m')?.hasError('minlength') && updateForm.get('ap_m')?.touched">
                Los nombres y apellidos deben tener al menos <br> 3 caracteres de longitud
            </span>
            <span class="error"
                *ngIf="updateForm.get('ap_m')?.hasError('maxlength') && updateForm.get('ap_m')?.touched">
                Los nombres y apellidos no pueden tener más de <br> 30 caracteres de longitud
            </span>
        </label>
        <label id="sexo">
            Elija un sexo:
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="H" name="sexo" id="sexoH" [(ngModel)]="sexo" formControlName="sexo"
                    [ngClass]="{'campo-invalido': updateForm.get('sexo')?.invalid && updateForm.get('sexo')?.touched}"
                    (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange(); isFieldValid('sexo')">
                Hombre
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" value="M" name="sexo" id="sexoM" [(ngModel)]="sexo" formControlName="sexo"
                    [ngClass]="{'campo-invalido': updateForm.get('sexo')?.invalid && updateForm.get('sexo')?.touched}"
                    (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange(); isFieldValid('sexo')">
                Mujer
            </label>
            <span class="error"
                *ngIf="updateForm.get('sexo')?.hasError('sexoInvalido') && updateForm.get('sexo')?.touched">
                La opción seleccionada no es válida
            </span>
        </label>
        <label id="apoyo_par">
            Apoyo recibido de los padres:
            <input type="number" name="apoyo_par" id="apoyo" min="0.0" max="10.0" step="0.1" [(ngModel)]="apoyo"
                formControlName="apoyo" (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange(); isFieldValid('apoyo')"
                [ngClass]="{'campo-invalido': updateForm.get('apoyo')?.invalid && updateForm.get('apoyo')?.touched}">
            <span class="error" *ngIf="(updateForm.get('apoyo')?.hasError('min')|| updateForm.get('apoyo')?.hasError('max'))
                && updateForm.get('apoyo')?.touched">
                La calificación no es válida, debe ser <br>
                mayor o igual a 1.0 y menor o igual a 10.0
            </span>
        </label>
        <label id="fecha_nac">
            Fecha de nacimiento:
            <input type="date" name="fecha_nac" id="nacimiento" [(ngModel)]="birthdate" formControlName="birthdate"
                [ngClass]="{'campo-invalido': updateForm.get('birthdate')?.invalid && updateForm.get('birthdate')?.touched}"
                (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange(); isFieldValid('birthdate')">
            <span class="error"
                *ngIf="updateForm.get('birthdate')?.hasError('validezFecha') && updateForm.get('birthdate')?.touched">
                Seleccione una fecha válida
            </span>
            <span class="error"
                *ngIf="updateForm.get('birthdate')?.hasError('antiguedadFecha') && updateForm.get('birthdate')?.touched">
                La fecha de nacimiento debe tener <br>
                al menos 4 años de antigüedad
            </span>
        </label>
        <label id="grupo">
            Seleccione el grupo:
            <select name="grupo" id="group" [(ngModel)]="grupo" formControlName="grupo"
                [ngClass]="{'campo-invalido': updateForm.get('grupo')?.invalid && updateForm.get('grupo')?.touched}"
                (ngModelChange)="onFieldChange(); isFieldValid('grupo')">
                <option value="0">Grupo</option>
                <option *ngFor="let g of listaGrupos" [value]="g.id_grupo">{{g.grupo}}</option>
            </select>
            <span class="error" *ngIf="updateForm.get('grupo')?.hasError('min') && updateForm.get('grupo')?.touched">
                Seleccione una opción válida
            </span>
        </label>
        <button type="button" (click)="volver()">Cancelar</button>
        <button type="submit" [disabled]="isFormEmpty||updateForm.invalid">Actualizar</button>
    </form>
    <span class="warning" *ngIf="isFormEmpty">
        ¡Debe llenar al menos un campo (además del id) para habilitar el botón de envío &#9888;!
    </span>
</div>
```

Adjunto capturas de la ejecución [image: Formulario en funcionamiento]
[image: Consola del navegador]

Comment: `FormsModule` y `ReactiveFormsModule` tienen que ir en el respectivo modulo, pero antes de eso tienes que decidirte, vas a usar los formularios normales o formularios reactivos? Sólo necesitas uno.

Comment: *a sugerencia de chatgpt* -> ufffff... y que la gente realmente piense que chatGPT sabe de lo que habla... qué miedo. De todas maneras... probaste a debugar un poco el problema?? Porque solo mirando tu código sin poder compilarlo está complicado... cuando se busca ayuda con la depuración es necesario darnos un [mre] porque si no, da muchísima pereza hacerlo nosotros mismos. Hay muchos sitios online donde puedes armar un mini proyecto para ejemplificar este problema, o simplemente mockea el servicio de tu código actual. Sobre todo, prueba a imprimir el `updateForm.errors` y ver qué hay ahí.